# make MSTest not building&deploying, and run on the same folder

Tags: testing, deployment, mstest

I have to run our tests with MSTest, the issue I have is that MSTest creates and operates in a number of subfolders (TestResults is the root one), and our tests are referencing some scripts in other parts of the project and therefore they're failing if executed from a different path than the solution one.

Is there any way I can force MSTest to not build and deploy the solution, but just run the tests on the same folder I'm launching it (i.e. bin/Debug)? I've been struggling with .testsettings files but could't get too far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your question right, but I think the answer is yes. And it is definitly so that mstest do not need to build an assembly. You can point to any assembly containing [TestClass] / [TestMethod] and mstest will run the tests without any compilation done.

Here is an example:
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

```
namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Simply build this in VS of with msbuild. That will create the following assembly. In my case that is:

```
UnitTest.dll
```

Under:

```
C:\tmp\unittest\UnitTest\UnitTest\bin\Debug
```

Then you simply run:

```
C:\tmp\unittest\UnitTest\UnitTest\bin\Debug>mstest /testcontainer:UnitTest.dll
```

Please not that you can point to any dll file here.

Output (and command):

```
C:\tmp\unittest\UnitTest\UnitTest\bin\Debug>mstest /testcontainer:UnitTest.dll
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading UnitTest.dll...
Starting execution...

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
Passed                UnitTest.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
1/1 test(s) Passed

Summary
-------
Test Run Completed.
  Passed  1
  ---------
  Total   1
Results file:  C:\tmp\unittest\UnitTest\UnitTest\bin\Debug\TestResults\jocke_DESKTOP-S6MP97G 2016-07-12 21_16_40.trx
Test Settings: Default Test Settings

C:\tmp\unittest\UnitTest\UnitTest\bin\Debug>
```

Comment: I'm executing the same command as you, from the /bin/debug folder. The problem is that MSBuild creates a TestResult folder, a "user_machine timestamp" folder, and an Out folder, containing all tests' dlls. My understanding is that it executes the dlls from the \TestResults\user_machine timestamp\Out folder, and my tests to pass they have to be executed from the /bin/debug folder.